# why on-failure policy doesn't restart a container that exited(137)

Tags: docker

below is the docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  ...
  node-app:
    restart: on-failure
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

according to `on-failure` policy, `on-failure` "Restart the container if it exits due to an error, which manifests as a non-zero exit code"

so after I compose up the container and press CTRL + C to send a `SIGINT` signal to stop the process, which results `exited(137)` for the container, but the container doesn't restart, why is that? isn't that `on-failure` restarts a container whose exit code is non-zero exited(0), `exited(137)` definitely requires a restart?

Answer (score 0):

Killing a container with `SIGINT` is somewhat different in the sense that this is considered to be *intentional* and so Docker Compose will not restart. Instead the container will stop *gracefully*.

It's worth thinking about where the signal is going though. If you are running `docker-compose up` in the foreground then `Ctrl-C` will be sending the signal to the Docker Compose process and not the container itself. To send a signal to a container you'd  use

```
docker kill --signal=SIGINT <container ID>
```